# Error converging ubuntu1604 on a mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, test-kitchen, kitchen-dokken

I am trying to create and after that converge a kitchen-dokken ubuntu-1604 image on a mac but I can't seem to get it working.

I have searched for three hours and that I know now is that it is because of systemd, that is only or mainly available for GNU/Linux.

I am using [kitchen-dokken by someara](https://github.com/someara/kitchen-dokken) because I couldn't create a test kitchen for ubuntu1604 with docker in the first place.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
my-mac:kitchen-dokken-master <user>$ kitchen create dokken-test-1251-ubuntu-1604

-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.11.1)
-----> Creating <dokken-test-1251-ubuntu-1604>...
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.
>>>>>>     Failed to complete #create action: [oci runtime error: exec: "/usr/lib/
systemd/systemd": stat /usr/lib/systemd/systemd: no such file or directory
] on dokken-test-1251-ubuntu-1604
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Can anybody tell me how I can do this on a mac or do I need to find another solution, like switching to Linux? Or someone to point me in the right direction.

I am glad for every comment or answer for this is driving me insane.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using docker in this case?

Comment: Yes. We See that docker instead of vagrant could speed up the process and I need to evaluate it.

Comment: As you see it may not work. Docker doesn't give you 'full-fledged' OS. Furthermore, you may encounter additional issues when testing low-level system interactions - like sysctl or iptables.

Comment: You may be right. I also encountered problems while trying to do some advanced network stuff (https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/#binding-ports). So I just stop at this point and use vagrant again. Thanks for your help.